# How is a frailty model in survival analysis expressed

Tags: cox-model, frailty

In some sources [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gW0PO7g6pY) one reads that the *frailty model* expands on the *cox proportional hazards model*
$$h_i(t|x_i)=h_0(t)\exp(\beta x_i)$$
by adding a *frailty* term $z$ like so
$$h_i(t|x_i,z_i)=h_0(t)\exp(\beta x_i+z_i)$$

In other sources I see *frailty* figuring as a factor “acting multiplicatively” [2](https://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/working/wp-2003-032.pdf) on the baseline hazard function $h_0(t)$
$$h_i(t|x_i,z_i)=z_ih_0(t)\exp(\beta x_i)$$

How are *individual frailty* and *shared frailty* correctly expressed?

[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gW0PO7g6pY): [Predicting Horse Race Winners Using Advanced Statistical Methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gW0PO7g6pY)

[2](https://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/working/wp-2003-032.pdf): [Frailty Models](https://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/working/wp-2003-032.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

These are essentially equivalent, except for a different interpretation of $z_i$ in the two representations. For [the exponential function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponential_of_Sum/Real_Numbers#Theorem),

$$\exp(x+y)=\exp(x) \exp(y) .$$

If you take $\exp(z_i)$ from the first representation

$$h_i(t|x_i,z_i)=h_0(t)\exp(\beta x_i+z_i)$$

you get $z_i$ in the second representation

$$h_i(t|x_i,z_i)=z_ih_0(t)\exp(\beta x_i).$$

The first representation is used for modeling in common R packages. In the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival), the `coxph()` function can model $z_i$ in $\exp(\beta x_i + z_i)$ with either a Gaussian, gamma, or *t* distribution. That's explained in Chapter 9 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842). The [`coxme` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=coxme) extends what you show as $z_i$ in the first representation to more complicated random effects with Gaussian distributions.